# infinite redirect loop after login from Azure Active Directory to web app - not HTTPS issue

Tags: azure, redirect, azure-active-directory, openid, openid-connect

I'm seeing some really strange behavior in one of my azure applications.  I'm using OpenID and Azure Active directory for logging into my site.  When I first deploy my application and log in, it works perfectly and will continue to work (log out and log back in) for that entire browser session.  However, if I try and log in from another computer, it gets stuck in an infinite redirect loop from the MS login page to my site.  If I then close my browser session and try logging in again, it also gets stuck in the loop....The login is only successful the first time after a new deployment.

I've had a similar problem in the past where I'm hitting the site on http and it's redirecting back from https, this is not the case here.

Here are some things I've tried to resolve this:

1. Update the app key in Azure AD
2. Recreate the app in Azure AD
3. Delete cookies on browser
4. Ensure I'm hitting https by forcing a redirect in web.config

I have several other applications in my same subscription that are working just fine and as best I can tell, this one is set up identically to those.

I'm fresh out of ideas of things to try here.

any suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Quick Edit:  We have dev, qa and prod/staging environments set up.  this is only happening in QA.  It doesn't do it when I debug from VS, it's fine in Dev, and also fine in staging.

Comment: Try capturing a fiddler network trace and see where the loop is happening and if there's anything unique about the request. Without more detail, I'm not sure why the app is behaving this way.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I switched from IIS Express to a local copy of IIS for debugging, and now I'm getting an infinite loop on login

Comment: @ScubaSteve no we never did resolve it.  Our QA team just ended up testing on Dev.  We spent a lot of time trying to fix this issue and never got anywhere so just worked around it.

Comment: I ended up solving this. I set a bunch of breakpoints in the authentication pipeline, and it turned out that IIS needed to be configured with a certificate (self signed is fine for test) for https. 

Our team is small (me and an IT guy), so the IT guy walked me through the server setup and it was solved.

Comment: We're using OpenIDConnect as well, so it should be solvable, if the issue is still relevant.